# Selenium with Chromedriver not successfully loading new page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning how to use Selenium with Python, and as a simple exercise I'm trying to click a button on a page. I've successfully located the button and clicked it, and I see the button physically get clicked, and the new page loads for a split second (I can see the URL path change) and then it reloads the page I was originally on. I don't run any other code after the button click.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I tried clicking the button using each of .click() and execute_script(). I also tried adding a call to time.sleep() after the button click.

code:

```
driver.get("website")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[text()='some text']").click()
l = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Search']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", l);
```

Comment: Could you please share your code sample

Comment: It seems like you are trying to click two different elements. Is this what you wanted? Could you also share a minimal example html of the website?

Comment: https://cityofla.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch - I'm selecting an item and then clicking the 'search' box. It looks like a line in the JS is forcing the URL in the textbox prior to the button click to be reloaded, but I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

This behavior might be due to JavaScript on the page or some other event handler interfering with the navigation. Here are some things you can try:

Instead of using implicitly_wait, use WebDriverWait along with ExpectedConditions to wait for the desired element to be clickable:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    driver.get("website")
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='some text']")))
    element.click()
    
    search_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Search']")))
    search_button.click()
```

or After clicking the button, wait for the URL to change or for an element to be present on the new page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("website")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='some text']")))
element.click()

search_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Search']")))
search_button.click()

# Wait for the URL to change
wait.until(EC.url_changes(driver.current_url))

# Or wait for an element to be present on the new page
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//element_on_new_page")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I tried both of these and I'm still seeing the same behavior: button gets clicked -> new URL loads for a split second -> original page refreshes. I was able to solve this with JeffC's answer above (click the button, wait for it to go stale, and the next click succeeds), but I still don't understand the root cause and I'd love to in case I come across another problem like this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the site. You click "Search All" and the page refreshes but does nothing. There are some other weird things here as well where elements are available but if you click them too early, it doesn't register.

Steps:

1. Navigate to the site and immediately click Search All. It doesn't work but it will the next time it's clicked but after all choices are set.
2. After clicking Search All, we need to wait for the page to reset. We do that by waiting for the Search All button to go stale (means the element reference is now bad because the page reloaded).
3. Set # of players
4. Set course(s)
5. Set date
   NOTE: date is set last because it opens a date picker that covers half the page. Setting the date last is simpler than having to deal with the date picker directly to have it close
6. Click Search All (again)

Now the search results page displays.

Anyway, the code below is working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = "https://cityofla.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
# search
search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-ng-click*='onSearchButtonClick']")))
search.click()
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(search))
# set # of people
Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pc")))).select_by_visible_text("2")
# choose courses
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='automationPadding']//label[text()='Griffith Park - Harding']").click()
# choose date
date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dateInput")))
date.clear()
date.send_keys("04/15/2023")
# search
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-ng-click*='onSearchButtonClick']").click()

# driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this out and it worked. Out of curiosity, I also tried clicking search all, waiting for the element to go stale, and then clicking search all again without making any further selections, and that worked as well. Do you know why the page refreshes but does nothing in the first case? And do you know why waiting for the element to go stale and clicking it again solves the problem? I Would love to learn how I can debug these types of issues in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I honestly don't know. It's just something I found through trial and error. It happens manually as well so I think the site is just poorly designed. Waiting for an element to go stale is something I learned years ago when I had a similar problem. It's a way to detect when the page is refreshing or transitioning to another page, etc.